# How to publish .snupkg Source Link package to MyGet using DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, myget

My build creates Source Link packages, in the form of `.snupkg` files, and I'd like to *push* those packages to MyGet.  From what I understand, tools such as Rider and Visual Studio can then download the symbols automatically.  I can get this `nuget push` command working from my local machine, but I cannot figure out how to push those symbols using a DevOps build task.  Here's my YAML:

```yaml
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Publish Symbols ($(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor).$(Build_Patch))'
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: 'projects/${{ parameters.projectName }}/src/**/bin/**/*.$(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor)*.snupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'external'
    publishFeedCredentials: 'MyGet - Test'
```

I'm absolutely sure that `MyGet - Test` is correct, since I'm using the exact URL and API key that the MyGet web UI tells me to use for publishing symbols, as well as the same ones I have working locally.  However, in the build logs I get:

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\6.4.0\x64\nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name redacted_source -Source https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_311668.config
Package source with Name: redacted_source added successfully.
Using authentication information for the following URI: https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\6.4.0\x64\nuget.exe setapikey *** -NonInteractive -Source redacted_source -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_311668.config
The API Key '***' was saved for 'https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json'.
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\6.4.0\x64\nuget.exe push D:\a\1\s\src\myproject\bin\Release\MyProject.1.10.24-beta.snupkg -NonInteractive -Source https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json -ApiKey *** -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_311668.config -Verbosity Detailed
Unable to load the service index for source https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json.
NuGet Version: 6.4.0.123
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

This does work a bit different than how I can successfully do this from the command line, which is:

```
nuget push .\MyProject.1.10.100-mike-beta.nupkg b848309c-0000-0000-0000-a893d8fc5d56 -Source https://company.myget.org/F/myfeed/api/v3/index.json
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to get the `NuGetCommand` task to behave like that.  It seems like both should work anyway.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out!  Though, the solution is kinda stupid.  You must use a pre-authenticated URL to push packages or symbols using the v3 API:

[image]

Authentication seems to work fine using the v2 API, but the v2 API doesn't let you push symbols.  I'm not sure if this is a limitation of MyGet or the DevOps NuGet task or what.  However, since the pre-authenticated URL can still live as a *secret* in the service connection, it's a fairly easy and secure workaround.

I'll leave this question open in case anyone has more insight or a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a service connection credential for the feed.

[image]

Then add ***NuGet authenticate*** task before ***NuGetCommand@2*** task in the pipeline.

```
steps:
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Authenticate'
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: feed
```

Please refer to the document [Publish NuGet packages with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-a-package).

Comment: Yea I messed around a bit with the `NuGetAuthenticate` task as well but also couldn't get anything working..  I think I wasn't able to figure out how to get it to use a service connection.  Maybe I'll mess around with it a bit more if I have some time, but for now what I have works..